# Django registration issues

Tags: python, django

I am trying to download registration application from github but i have some problems: 
- git clone https://github.com/macropin/django-registration.git
- python install setup.py 
- i copied the registration folder to my project folder 
Than :

***Url.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import *

from django.contrib import admin

from registration.views import*


urlpatterns = ['',
    url (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
]
```

***Setting.py:***

```
INSTALLED_APPS = 
(

'django.contrib.admin',

'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# additional external apps
'registration',
'social.apps.django_app.default',

)

SITE_ID=1

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7

REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
```

When I type python manage.py sqlall 
**the result is this error :

**manage.py sqlall: error: Enter at least one application label.**

Please any help ?

Comment: Enter at least one application label

Comment: I entered the name of the application registration in the settings

Comment: with this error 


Using the URLconf defined in dss.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^accounts/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

Comment: with your last comment it seems that the error is no longer related to the `sqlall` command. You need to map the empty url to a view.

Comment: As @e4c5 states, you need to enter an app label, see the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#s-sqlall-app-label-app-label